# Scrollable table in react using only css and tailwind with last 2 columns fixed on mobile view

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have a table in ReactJS and the table is a very large one, so on mobile view I want to make it scrollable both sides, I did that thing but now when it's on smaller screens, I want to have the last 2 columns fixed along with their headers.
Any help or links would be appreciated

Comment: Could you add the current code you have for the table?

Comment: a codesandbox link would be fine?